# why can not write 1 in tracing_on file system

Tags: android, kernel, trace, ftrace

I tried to use  dynamic ftrace in android kernel (shamu which it is for nexous 6).

According to [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/ftrace#dftrace) when enabled configs and rebuilt kernel.

I couldn't write `1` on `tracing_on`.

```
shamu:/d/tracing # echo 1>tracing_on;
1|shamu:/d/tracing # cat tracing_on;
0
```

how can I enable it ?

Comment: Add a space between `1` and `>`. Otherwise, bash treats combination `1>` in a special way.